# Away around Error: There is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table

Tags: sql, postgresql

Been at this for some time now. I'm getting this psql error when attepmting to create a joins table (product_type_combo):

> There is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table product

I'm receiving this because the field (customer) I'm referencing from the table product does not have a UNIQUE constraint.

```
CREATE TABLE product 
(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    customer VARCHAR,
    CONSTRAINT product_c01 UNIQUE (name)
);

CREATE TABLE product_type_combo 
(
    customer VARCHAR REFERENCES product(customer),
    type_id INT REFERENCES type(id),
    PRIMARY KEY (customer, type_id),
    CONSTRAINT product_type_combo_c01 UNIQUE (customer, type_id)
);
```

I don't want to have a UNIQUE constraint on the customer field on the product table since I want duplicates to appear there. I only want the customer & type combo in the joins table to have a constraint.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

This is silly:

```
customer VARCHAR REFERENCES product(customer),
```

You have a primary key on the table, an `id` column.  You should be using that.

You *could* define `customer` to be `unique` -- the lack of a unique constraint on a column used for a foreign key reference is the cause of the error.  However, I strongly, strongly recommend that you use the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming from the Foreign Key (`REFERENCES`) constraint, for reasons [listed in the PostgreSQL manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK):

> A foreign key must reference columns that either are a primary key or form a unique constraint.

Since your "customer" column is not unique, it cannot be the target of a foreign key reference. It also suggests a problem in your data model:

- If the relationship is between a *product* and a *type*, then referencing the "id" from the products table would make sense.
- If the relationship is between a *customer* and a *type*, then there should be a table listing all the possible customers, and you can create foreign keys referencing that from both "product" and "product_type_combo" (which would presumably be better named "customer_type_combo").